# Plotting more than one variable in ggplot2 - scatter and line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I had to edit the question. At the end of the day it makes more sense this way.
So I'm trying to graphically determine the activities depending on the sun of certain animals.

I created a graph here that shows the sunrise and sunset. Also, the dots represent the releases.
However, instead of geom_errorbar(), I would like to map one line each for sunrise and one each for sunset.

The code that I have used looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

d$Photo.date = as.Date(d$Photo.Date)
d$Photo.time = hms(d$Photo.time)
d$up_dt <- ymd_hms(d$up)
d$down_dt <- ymd_hms(d$down)

ggplot(d) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = date(up_dt), 
                    ymin = hour(up_dt)+1/60*minute(up_dt), 
                    ymax = hour(down_dt)+1/60*minute(down_dt)),
                lwd = 3, color = "light grey")+
  geom_count(aes(x = Photo.date, y = Photo.time@hour + Photo.time@minute/60))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24,4), name = "Uhrzeit", 
                     labels = c("0:00", "4:00", "8:00", "12:00", 
                                "16:00", "20:00", "23:59")) +
  xlab("Datum")
```

How can I work with two lines for sunrise and sunset instead of geom_errorbar()?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What you want to do is eminently doable with ggplot2.  You can use `geom_ribbon` to plot your sunrise/sunset data and `geom_point` to plot your releases.  You can identify different types of releases by using aesthetics.  One important principle to follow is to keep your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). There are many, many tutorials on the tidyverse online.  For ggplot2 in particular, [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) is a good place to start.  Without some sample data, it's difficult to provide concrete advice.

Comment: Don't be surprised if this question is downvoted or even closed.  It doesn't ask a specific programming question anddoesn't include a *minimum working example*.  You may want to edit it having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Great!  we are making progress.  Now, if you could add the output from `dput(d)` [or `dput(head(d))` if `d` is large], we will have some data to work with and I am sure that someone will help you.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to provide the data. I am sorry but I am trying to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

Untested code as you haven't given us access to `d`...

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = date(up_dt), 
                    ymin = hour(up_dt)+1/60*minute(up_dt), 
                    ymax = hour(down_dt)+1/60*minute(down_dt)),
                lwd = 3, color = "light grey")+
  geom_count(aes(x = Photo.date, y = Photo.time@hour + Photo.time@minute/60))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24,4), name = "Uhrzeit", 
                     labels = c("0:00", "4:00", "8:00", "12:00", 
                                "16:00", "20:00", "23:59")) +
  xlab("Datum")
```

or

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date(up_dt), 
                    y = hour(up_dt)+1/60*minute(up_dt), 
                lwd = 3, color = "light grey")+
  geom_line(aes(x = date(up_dt), 
                    y = hour(down_dt)+1/60*minute(down_dt)),
                lwd = 3, color = "light grey")+
  geom_count(aes(x = Photo.date, y = Photo.time@hour + Photo.time@minute/60))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24,4), name = "Uhrzeit", 
                     labels = c("0:00", "4:00", "8:00", "12:00", 
                                "16:00", "20:00", "23:59")) +
  xlab("Datum")
```